# Proper roles for a backup-only user on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, backup, permissions, role

I am working on new processes and policies for my PostgreSQL databases when they are first created, and I am trying to define what role attributes are necessary for a role specifically used for backups. I have found for MySQL that the grants `SELECT, PROCESS, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER` are enough for a user to perform backups, but I can't figure out how to translate grants like this to PostgreSQL.

Any recommendations, other than having to rely on `Superuser`?

Comment: For pg_dump to work (which isn't really a backup) the user only needs SELECT privilege on all tables (and sequences) that should be dumped. The predefined role `pg_read_all_data` might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a logical backup (dump), you need `CONNECT` on the database, `USAGE` on all schemas and `SELECT` on tables and sequences. The role must be defined as `LOGIN`.

For a file system backup with `pg_dump`, you need a role with the `REPLICATION` setting.

Comment: Thanks! I set up all of the grants accordingly, and the backup user works. Just need to test the backup, but all appears good!